# Animation-list (animationDrawable) autostart

Tags: android, android-animation

Is it possible to set `animation-list` drawable to autostart after inflating from XML without using `AnimationDrawable.start()`?

My `animation-list`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/download_light" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/download20" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/download40" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/download60" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/download80" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/download_on" android:duration="300" />
</animation-list>
```

Comment: funny.. my problem is taht it DOES auto-start :)  android:targetSdkVersion="18"

Comment: There was a bug in AnimationDrawable.setVisible() that would cause animations to auto-start under some circumstances. There is not currently an API for auto-starting based on the drawable XML, however you can modify your view to auto-start animations. ProgressBar, for example, does this.

Answer (score 6):

Auto-start:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/wave"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  />
```

NOT Auto-start:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/wave"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  />
```

It means that when you set the animation-list drawble as the background, it will not auto start until you call `AnimationDrawable.start()`. Hope this can help you.

Comment: After Lollipop xml autostart of animation doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 1):

After test on some device with different API, I found:
**Without** using `AnimationDrawable.start()`

- In almost devices `animation-list` **will not** auto start
- In few devices (almost device 4.4) **will** auto start

Therefore, I think we should always use `AnimationDrawable.start()` and `AnimationDrawable.stop()` for start/stop animation

Answer (score 1):

you can set AnimationDrawable as ProgressBar android:indeterminateDrawable, then AnimationDrawable will start automatically when ProgressBar become visible

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="1dp"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:maxWidth="10000dp"
        android:maxHeight="10000dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/indeterminate_progess_animation_drawable" />
```